# Horizontal scrollview object limit ?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I was trying my code on my i pad and it crashed. There is nothing on device logs but unknown type and unknown process. So i did dig. I tot it was a memory problem. What i figured out that i cannot add so many images on a horizontal scrollview. I have 100+ of them.

This is my code

```
for(int index=0; index < 166; index++)
{

UIImageView *imgscv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgscv.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 250);
imgscv.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 5, 200, 250);
imgscv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",index-1]];
[images insertObject:imgscv atIndex:index];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
[scrollview addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
xOffset += 205;
}
```

When i changed the upper limit of index in the for-loop to 16 everything is fine.So is that it ? Is there a limit ? Any fixes or alternatives you may suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just load the visible part of the scrollview, and then use

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
```

responder and draw others in there after scroll. Would save a lot of performance

Comment: Paging solved my problem. Loading previous, current and the next pages and releasing the rest is the trick i guess. Thanks for the insight.